# Why is the SD-card mounted to "/sdcard/external_sd" instead of "/sdcard" (or "/mnt/sdcard")?

Tags: external-sd, storage

I recently upgraded my phone to an LG Motion 4G (Android 4 ICS). I see that the sdcard is mounted at `/sdcard/external_sd`. I also noticed that this appears to be the same with some other newer models. Apps expect the sdcard to be at `/sdcard`. I assume the manufacturers want to include a lot of internal storage, but why mount internal storage at `/sdcard`? Shouldn't this be against some form of Android specification standard?

Comment: As to the "specification standard", this should rise no problems: As you can read in the developers documentation on [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), apps should determine the location/availibility using API calls (here: [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())), not using hard-coded paths.

Comment: Good point Izzy, but apparently some manufacturers are wrongfully redirecting apps to the internal space via getExternalStorageDirectory(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0

Comment: Ah, good point as well -- as a non-developer I was not aware of that. But I see Flow provided a very good explanation -- again with points I was not aware of...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason is the history of Android: The first generation of Android devices only had a small amount of internal storage (around 100-400MiB) which was mounted under `/data`.

Next, devices with a, at that time external, SD-card came out. The SD card was mounted under `/mnt/sdcard`.

After that, devices with large internal storage came on the market. This storage was portioned, because `/mnt/sdcard` had become the default place for big data chunks from apps, pictures and such. So the Android environment had to have a `/data` and `/mnt/sdcard` directory. Therefore one partition was for `/data`, the other for `/mnt/sdcard`. This is the reason why you storage space could become low (the `/data` partition) even if there is plenty of space on `/mnt/sdcard`.

This situation was improved with Android 3.0: `/data` and `/mnt/sdcard` are now pointing to the same partition. <sup>Good job Google, that could have been done versions ago.</sup> Which is also the reason why app2sd is no more needed on Android 3.0 or higher: You would only move the data within the same volume.

Now we come to the answer if your question: Since `/mnt/sdcard` is already mounted on the internal storage, an external SD-card has to use a different mount point. And this mount point is not specified by Google. It could be

- `/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd`
- `/mnt/external`
- `/mnt/extSdCard`
- `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd`
- etc.

The API call [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) usually points to the internal storage directory. This behavior is documented. There are [open source projects that provide tools](https://github.com/jow-ct/Environment2) to find the external SD-card directory in a canonical way.

Comment: Does that mean there is no "transparent way" for apps to determine the SD card? Of course, there's [`isExternalStorageRemovable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable()) to see if the "external" storage is removable, plus one could determine the mount points (using the `mount` command) and check for mount flags etc. But if I'm not taken wrong here, this still means each developer needs to figure out for his app himself, and there's no simple API call to do that for him?

Comment: That's correct. There are the libraries that I linked that try to add that feature, but there is no official API call to do so.

Comment: If both the external storage and the `/data` partition are merged, how could I safely mount/unmount my SD card to plug it, say, in my PC? It seems to me that having separate partitions is logical and I don't see why all that had to happen.

Comment: It's not the external storage, it's the, so called, "internal SD" and the `/data` partition that get's merged.

Comment: `This situation was improved with Android 3.0: /data and /mnt/sdcard are now pointing to the same parition`. Just FYI, that's NOT true on at least one phone running Android 4.0 (Pantech Burst), where `/data` is a 1GB ext4 partition and `/mnt/sdcard` is a 12GB FAT32 partition.

Comment: All statements are with vanilla Android in mind. Manufacturers are free to leave the path Google has set.

Comment: Shame on Google for not providing an API call to unambiguously detect the mount point, or at the very least specify a "recommended" mount point (rather than leaving manufacturers to each invent their own). The Environment2 project on GitHub (thanks for linking to it) does ease the pain, but too bad the (extensive) documentation in the code is all in German.

Comment: Just as an example, I'm using Android 6.0.1 and my external SD card is mounted at `/storage/{random numbers, e.g. 3430-3234}`, which Astro renames to `/storage/SD card`.

Answer (score 4):

Forcing external SD mount away from `/mnt/sdcard` has no technical merit, it is Google's way of helping hardware vendors to create a differentiation point for phones with more internal memory.

There is no reason why applications have to find a way to locate the external card when `/mnt/sdcard` was clearly the place the sdcard should have been and Google's undefined way of loading external SD card is another less than consumer friendly plot to make external SD card less useful in newer Android devices. There is NO reason why `/data` and `/mnt/sdcard` had to be merged into the same partition on newer version of Android except for manufacturer to differentiate phones with larger internal memory from lower cost units with less internal memory. Even if the merge had to be done, Google could have clearly defined a *STANDARD* new mounting point for the external SD cards instead of leaving it completely vague. This is completely working against preventing further "segmentation" of the Android eco-system by a clumsy design to help vendor differentiation of higher end phones against lower cost units with less built-in memory.

Android app binaries are tiny, phones with 1-2 Gigs of internal memory should have way more than enough space for hundreds of apps, and all the large data could be safely tucked way on an external SD card. But then vendors realized they had to have a way to differentiate their higher end product, and claiming a higher internal memory become part of that scheme and crippling the usefulness of external memory is the other integrated part this scheme required for this to work fully hence the less helpful API to find external sd cards and the unstandardized mounting points.

So: No, mounting SD card at a place other than `/mnt/sdcard` is nothing but a business strategy for selling higher priced new phones under newer version of Android, nothing more than that. Just imagine, if the Nexus 4 8GB and Nexus 16GB can both use 64GB of external sd card for application and media, is there a reason for anyone to buy the 16 GB version? That extra 8 GB of NAND memory is not surely not worth $50 price difference if external SD cards are involved.  Since most components in a smart phone pretty much has to be the same (RAM, processor, radios), the only area left for more profit margin is the internal memory space, and hence the weird external memry mounting point.

Also has everyone also noticed the absence of external SD support from current crop of "Google" branded android devices? This trend will keep expanding in "top tier" Android devices. External SD card support was a key differentiation for Android devices to overtake iPhone's dominance in mobile market. Now with Android ruling supreme in the numbers game, there's little need for this profit sapping practice to be up kept for much longer.

I won't be surprised by Android 5.0, the external SD card support would be a thing of the past. Because if it's hard to apps to find externals SD card, then most program will just simply use the known `/data` and `/mnt/sdcard` locations, with most apps use more and more stored data for its operation, a vibrant product mark up strategy is created out of "thin air" simply by not mount external SD card at `/mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: Now, that is what I call a *wall of text*. Seems also a bit ranty. Please add some paragraphs to your answer. Also I don't get why there is "no reason to merge `/data` and  `/mnt/sdcard`", as I clearly see a reason: Avoiding the fragmentation of the internal storage.

Comment: That was definitely a rant, Deecee, but regardless, I appreciate your input. Cheers

Comment: And there's one thing more to it: with devices placing the xternal SD card *inside* the internal one (e.g. `/sdcard/external_sd` on the LG P880), backing up "shared storage" *includes both*, and creates a huge archive. No way to backup the internal SD only in an easy approach. Which doesn't make much sense, as there are much easier ways to backup the external card. A fact which makes me crazy, as I have the mentioned device...

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware (if rooted) you can go into /system/etc/vold.fstab and swap the mount points for /sdcard and /mnt/external_sd....this will allow your sdcard to be on /sdcard as you expect and the remaining "internal storage" will be mounted on /mnt/external_sd or if you prefer /sdcard/external_sd/

Comment: This works with some models of phones, but not all. It doesn't work for my LG Motion 4G, Android 4.0.4. Thx